# Suggested Edit Reviews - Design Error with "Reject and Edit"

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits, design

I just noticed a minor bug when I clicked "Reject and Edit" in the Suggested Edit Review Queue. When I click on "more", my username is listed, but with having 0 edits approved and 0 edits rejected. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6012669):

[image: bug example]

I think that my user should be hidden, or the number of approved/rejected edits should be filled in like when I clicked "Reject" or "Approve".

Comment: I like option (C) - Add a 3rd category and indicate how many edits were Improved (Reject & Edit + Approve & Edit)

Comment: @psubsee2003 Great idea, but should that edits also be counted to approved/rejected ones? And when I click "Improve Edit", my username is hidden